# How to ensure that users inside and outside docker are consistent?

Tags: docker, containers, gem5, podman

I am making a Docker image. I would like to have a ready-made environment in there as well as some ready-made directories. In this way, I only need to mount some of my directories and use them directly. I made the image using the Dockerfile below. In order to have the same permissions inside and outside the container (not root), I created a `user` user.

```
FROM matthewfeickert/docker-python3-ubuntu:latest

USER root
# Create an arbitrary non-root user; we don't care about its uid
# or other properties
RUN useradd --system user

RUN sudo pip config set global.index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple

RUN set -x; \
        sudo  apt-get update \
        && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo  apt-get install -y  build-essential git-core m4 zlib1g zlib1g-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev swig xz-utils gdb git \
        && sudo -H python3  -m pip install scons==3.0.1 \
        && sudo -H python3  -m pip install six  


# RUN apt-get -y install gdb

RUN apt-get clean

RUN git config --global url."https://hub.fastgit.xyz/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

WORKDIR /usr/local/src

RUN git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git

RUN sudo chown user /usr/local/src/gem5 -R

USER user

# RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/gem5/build

# RUN sudo chown user /usr/local/src/gem5/build 

WORKDIR /usr/local/src/gem5/
```

After making the image, I mount my directory into it.

```
docker run  -it --rm  \
-v my_dir/runScripts:/usr/local/src/gem5/runScripts   \
-v my_dir/gem5/src:/usr/local/src/gem5/src  \
-v my_dir/gem5/configs:/usr/local/src/gem5/configs \
-v my_dir/gem5/programs:/usr/local/src/gem5/programs 
-v my_dir/gem5/build:/usr/local/src/gem5/build  \
-v my_dir/gem5/results:/usr/local/src/gem5/results \
-v my_dir/gem5/update.sh:/usr/local/src/gem5/update.sh  \
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined --user 1000:1000 gerrie/gem5:v1  "/bin/bash"
```

When I enter the docker container, I output the UID at this time.

```
$ echo $UID
1000
```

This is the same as outside the container.

What I think is that the inside and outside of the gem5 directory should be exactly the same user. But it's not.

```
$ ll
total 232
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 09:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4096 Jun 16 03:16 ../
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root     984 Jun 16 03:17 .git-blame-ignore-revs
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root     645 Jun 16 03:17 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root   19339 Jun 16 03:17 .mailmap
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    5595 Jun 16 03:17 CODE-OF-CONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root   26112 Jun 16 03:17 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    2332 Jun 16 03:17 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    1478 Jun 16 03:17 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    7790 Jun 16 03:17 MAINTAINERS.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    2133 Jun 16 03:17 README
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root   34435 Jun 16 03:17 RELEASE-NOTES.md
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user   root   28876 Jun 16 03:17 SConstruct*
-rw-r--r--  1 user   root    8616 Jun 16 03:17 TESTING.md
drwxrwxr-x  2 docker docker  4096 Jun 16 08:52 build/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 build_opts/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 build_tools/
drwxrwxr-x 13 docker docker  4096 Jun 16 08:54 configs/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 ext/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 include/
drwxrwxr-x  2 docker docker  4096 Jun 16 09:03 programs/
-rw-rw-r--  1 docker docker     0 Jun 16 08:58 results
drwxrwxr-x  2 docker docker  4096 Jun 16 02:33 runScripts/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 site_scons/
drwxrwxr-x 17 docker docker  4096 Jun 16 02:33 src/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 system/
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 tests/
-rw-rw-r--  1 docker docker     0 Jun 16 08:58 update.sh
drwxr-xr-x  1 user   root    4096 Jun 16 03:17 util/
```

All the directories I mount belong to the `docker` user, and all other directories are `user`.
I am able to create files inside my mounted directory. But for gem5's directory, I don't even have permission to create files.
But according to the Dockfile, I have clearly chown this directory to `user`. And when entering the container, I set the `uid`.

```
docker@7df3004beb2a:/usr/local/src/gem5$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
docker@7df3004beb2a:/usr/local/src/gem5$ cd runScripts/
docker@7df3004beb2a:/usr/local/src/gem5/runScripts$ touch test
docker@7df3004beb2a:/usr/local/src/gem5/runScripts$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 docker docker 4096 Jun 16 09:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user   root   4096 Jun 16 09:12 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker docker    0 Jun 16 09:13 test
```

When I compile, this problem occurs. I think this is caused by a permissions issue. Where did I go wrong? How should I modify it? Thanks a lot!

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/usr/local/src/gem5/fatal: unsafe repository ('/usr/local/src/gem5' is owned by someone else)\nTo add an exception for this directory, call:\n\n\tgit config --global --add safe.directory /usr/local/src/gem5/hooks"`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question was tagged with **podman** (in addition to **docker**), here is a Podman solution to the problem of mapping users between the host and the container:

If you want to map your regular user on the host to a user with the same UID inside the container, you could add the Podman option `--userns=keep-id`.  A more general solution (that also works when the UIDs are not the same) can be found in the troubleshooting.md [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#33-container-creates-a-file-that-is-not-owned-by-the-users-regular-uid) and [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem). The tips make use of the options **--uidmap** and **--gidmap**.  (I wrote those tips).

The two options  **--uidmap** and **--gidmap** may look to be a bit complicated to use, but as soon as you understand how rootless Podman maps UIDs and GIDs it will be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I tried this method, but this one partially works. When I add --userns=keep-id, I mount the file and I can access it normally. But noticed that I created the User user in the dockerfile, is there any way to make them point to the same？ Thanks!

Comment: If I don't specify the UID, then after I go in container, I can create the file normally, the username is USER. But when I specify the UID, this completely shows up a new user. But I want out-mirror and in-mirror to refer to the same user.

Comment: I wonder what UID is given to new user __user__ as a result of the command `useradd --system user`? Maybe you could check by running `grep user /etc/passwd` inside the container.

Comment: grep user /etc/passwd
user:x:999:999::/home/user:/bin/sh
cuiyujie@b93ed61a9291:/usr/local/src/gem5$ echo $UID
1004

Comment: The UID of the User created in the Dockerfile is 999. The UID inside and outside the container is 1004 (when UID is specified). This makes me unable to access files belonging to User inside the container. Is there any way to make them point to the same UID?

Comment: Ok you need to map your regular user on the host (UID 1004) to the user __user__  (UID 999) inside the container? To do that follow the solution provided in the troubleshooting tips ( in the troubleshooting.md [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#33-container-creates-a-file-that-is-not-owned-by-the-users-regular-uid) and [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem)) Both tips are more or less the same.

Comment: It's embarrassing. I want to write it inside Makefile. But how to perform addition and subtraction in Makefile? For example --uidmap $(($uid+1)):$(($uid+1)):$(($subuidSize-$uid)) . I googled it, but it's all Makefiles for compiling programs normally. In the Makefile, addition and subtraction become empty strings.

Comment: Thanks! My modified Makefile is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646657/how-to-write-numeric-expressions-in-makefile