# How to write numeric expressions in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to write statements about Podman in Makefile. A UID mapping is used here.  But I found that I was always unable to do numerical calculations.
Below is my Makefile. But here ${uid}+1 and similar operations will become empty strings. How should I solve this problem?
Thanks!

```
HOST_GEM5 := /mnt/disk/cuiyujie/workspace/workGem5/gem5
SIM := ${HOST_GEM5}/X86/gem5.opt
SHELL := /bin/bash
DOCKER_GEM5 := /usr/local/src/gem5


subuidSize=$(shell $(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.UIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 )))
subgidSize=$(shell $(( $(podman info --format "{{ range .Host.IDMappings.GIDMap }}+{{.Size }}{{end }}" ) - 1 )))
uid := $(shell id -u)
gid := $(shell id -g)




DOCKER_DIRS_MAP := \
    -v ${HOST_GEM5}/runScripts:${DOCKER_GEM5}/runScripts


MAP_CMD := \
    --user ${uid}:${gid} \
    --uidmap ${uid}:0:1 \
    --uidmap 0:1:${uid} \
    --uidmap $(($uid+1)):$(($uid+1)):$(($subuidSize-$uid)) \
    --gidmap ${gid}:0:1 \
    --gidmap 0:1:${gid} \
    --gidmap $(($gid+1)):$(($gid+1)):$(($subgidSize-$gid)) 




.PHONY: default clean run build



default: build

build:
    podman run  -it --rm  ${DOCKER_DIRS_MAP} --security-opt seccomp=unconfined  \
    ${MAP_CMD}  \
    gerrie/gem5:v1  "/bin/bash" 



clean:
    rm -rf ${HOST_GEM5}/build/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Make always uses `/bin/sh` as the shell it invokes, both for recipes and for `$(shell ...)` functions.  `/bin/sh` is a POSIX-conforming shell.  The syntax you're using is not POSIX shell syntax: it's special enhanced syntax that is only available in the `bash` shell.

You can either rewrite your scripting to work in POSIX shells (probably by using the `expr` program to do the math), or add this to your makefile to tell it you want to use `bash` instead of `/bin/sh`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Note, of course, that your makefile will now no longer work on any system that doesn't have a `/bin/bash` shell.

Comment: But after I added it, $((${id}+1)) is still empty string.

Comment: @Gerrie You need to be careful with `$` characters and parentheses. e.g. something like --gidmap $(($gid+1)) should probably be --gidmap $$(($(gid)+1)) to prevent make evaluating the expression as a whole.

Comment: To expand on @G.M. -- `$(expr)` will get evaluated at make parse time, and make does not know how to simplify the expression.   You need to use `$$(expr)`, which make will resolve to `$(expr)`, and then pass that to the shell which would then evaluate your expression.

Comment: Yes, apologies.  You also have to escape your `$` as suggested above.